# Ember on Firebase Hosting not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am attempting to deploy my ember app on Firebase. I've followed these steps:

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
$ ember build --prod
$ firebase login
$ firebase init
```

However when I visit the URL after I deploy I just get a message saying

```
 Welcome to Firebase Hosting

 You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting.
 Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!
```

I now can't even seem to load up my application locally, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you also running `firebase deploy`?

Comment: Also, are you sure you didn't overwrite your index file when you ran `firebase init` after running `ember build`

Comment: I think I may have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your public folder. If any index.html exists, just delete it. try to make new build then deploy it again.

hope this help